# list oldest file in directories in a loop

Tags: bash, array, diff, for

I have a set of files in a structure like so;

```
regions
├── ap-northeast-1
│   └── sg-66497903
│       ├── sg-66497903-2017-10-03-Tue-12.39.json
│       ├── sg-66497903-2017-10-03-Tue-12.42.json
│       ├── sg-66497903-2017-10-03-Tue-12.49.json
│       ├── sg-66497903-2017-10-03-Tue-12.53.json
│       └── sg-66497903-2017-10-03-Tue-13.12.json
├── ap-northeast-2
│   └── sg-824282eb
│       ├── sg-824282eb-2017-10-03-Tue-12.39.json
│       ├── sg-824282eb-2017-10-03-Tue-12.42.json
│       ├── sg-824282eb-2017-10-03-Tue-12.49.json
│       ├── sg-824282eb-2017-10-03-Tue-12.53.json
│       └── sg-824282eb-2017-10-03-Tue-13.12.json
├── ap-south-1
│   └── sg-4fec0526
│       ├── sg-4fec0526-2017-10-03-Tue-12.39.json
│       ├── sg-4fec0526-2017-10-03-Tue-12.42.json
│       ├── sg-4fec0526-2017-10-03-Tue-12.49.json
│       ├── sg-4fec0526-2017-10-03-Tue-12.53.json
│       └── sg-4fec0526-2017-10-03-Tue-13.12.json
```

The list is longer but you get the idea. I am trying to find the oldest json file in each directory to use as at the standard to set in an array and `diff` the other files in the individual directories.

I have this so far, but it's not right.

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t awsReg < <(ls ~/regions)

for awsrg in "${awsReg[@]}"
do
    mapfile -t awsSG < <(ls regions/"$awsrg")
       for sg in "${awsSG[@]}"
         do 
            find "$sg" -mindepth 2 -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -n 1
diff -q ##oldest file## ##all other files###
  done
done
```

For example I would like in `regions -> ap-northeast-1 -> sg-66497903` to find the file `sg-66497903-2017-10-03-Tue-12.39.json`, set it as the file to `diff` the other files in the directory with a `diff -q`. Move on to next directory, find the oldest in that directory....etc

Comment: Why don't you just use ls -tQ | tail -1 to get the olders file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier in `zsh`:

```
for sg in ~/region/ap-*/sg-*(/); do
  files=($sg/sg-*.json(N.Om)) # list of json regular files sorted
                              # from oldest to newest
  if (($#files >= 2)); then
    oldest=$files[1]
    files[1]=()
    for file in $files; do
      cmp -s $oldest $file ||
        printf '"%s" differs from "%s"\n' $file $oldest
    done
  fi
done
```

With `ksh93` or `bash` and GNU `ls`, you could translate that to:

```
for sg in ~/region/ap-*/sg-*/; do
  eval "files=($(ls --quoting-style=shell-always -rtd -- "$sg"sg-*.json))"
  if ((${#files[@]} >= 2)); then
    oldest=${files[1]}
    files=("${files[@]:1}")
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
      cmp -s "$oldest" "$file" ||
        printf '"%s" differs from "%s"\n' "$file" "$oldest"
    done
  fi
done
```

Comment: bash is complaining about the * (asterisk) in the for path. Can I incorporate them into an array?

Comment: @eekfonky, not sure what you mean, there's no reason why bash would complain about `*` there. Are you saying that that glob doesn't match any file?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't like the glob. I figured it out. I have many more directories without the 'ap'. My mistake

Answer (score 1):

Well you have the file very well named - from most significant value to least so even simple text sort will do it
In each directly you can do in bash

```
myfile=$(ls -1 *.json| sort | head -1)
```

this will set your variable $myfile to what you need and diff-away as much as you need

to get the other files all but your myfile

```
ls -1 *.json | grep -v $myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to use something like:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    unset -v oldest
    oldest() 
    { local files f old; files=("${1:-.}"/*)
    old="${files[0]}"
     for f in "${files[@]}"
      do [[ $f -ot $old ]] && old=$f ;done
      printf '%s\n' "$old"
    }
```

Call the script as in: `./oldest regions/*`